# How to check whether two elements in a braid group are conjugate using a software?

Tags: group-theory, math-software, computational-algebra

How to check whether two elements in a braid group are conjugate using a software?

For example, let $Br_n$ be the braid group generated by $T_1, T_2, \ldots, T_{n-1}$ subject to the relations $ T_i T_j T_i = T_j T_i T_j $ if $|i-j|=1$ and $T_i T_j = T_j T_i$ if $|i-j|>1$.

I want to check that if $T_2 T_1^{-1} T_3^{-1} T_2^{-1} T_5$ and $T_2 T_1 T_3^{-1} T_2^{-1} T_5^{-1}$ are conjugate or not.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by "or not using software"? Does "or" mean "and"?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, sorry for the confusing. I added " " to "two elements in a braid group are conjugate or not".

Comment: To make the title and question easier to read, you can replace "that" by "whether" and then you can also leave out the "or not" as that is implied by the use of "whether".

Comment: @Tobias, thank you very much for your suggestions. I edited the post.

Comment: No, I meant replace the "that" (i.e. get rid of it) and also remove the "or not". Then you don't need any quotation marks to make the sentence understandable.

Comment: @Tobis, thank you very much for your suggestions.